# (Angular 2/4/5/6) Nested subscribe methods with multiple http requests

Tags: angular, angular6, subscription, subscribe

I need to call a subscribe method within a subscribe method.

In the first subscribe method, it returns me a deviceid which is subsequently used in the second subscribe method.

```
result=[];
idArray=[2,4];

this.subscription =
    this.quoteService.get(this.quoteid) //first api call
     .subscribe((quote: Quote) => {   
       this.deviceid = quote["deviceid"]; 
       this.faultService.get(this.deviceid) //second api call
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe((faultGroup: FaultGroup[]) => {
        faultGroup.forEach(({ faults }) => {
          //execute logic for 2nd subscription
          if (faults) {
            faults
              .filter(
                ({ id }) => this.idArray.indexOf(id) > -1,
              )
              .forEach(fault => this.result.push(fault.name));
          }
          //end of logic
        });
      });
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
});
```

Can someone teach me how to use flatMap/switchMap to avoid using a nested subscribe? Appreciate your help!

Comment: What is `first()`? a synchronous method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here your requirement is to return then result from the second API, it's just that to call the second API, you need the result from the first. For this, `switchMap()` suites you best. Use it like explained in the code.

```
this.subOb = this.quoteService.get(this.quoteid) //first api call
    .pipe(switchMap((quote: Quote) => {
          // result of first API call here
        this.deviceid = quote["deviceid"];
          // you need to return the second observable from inside the switcMap
          // and this will only be executed after the first Observable(first API call) is finished
        return this.faultService.get(this.deviceid) //second api call
          // need some mode logic after second API call is done? call first()?
          // map the result with a pipe
            .pipe(map(secondData) => { 
                  // If you aren't manipulating the data 
                  // to be returned, then use tap() instead of map().
                return data;
            })

    }))
        .subscribe((data) => {
            // only one subscription is required.
            // this will have data from second API call
        })
```

Use the `ngOnDestroy()` hook to `unsubcribe()` for the `Subscriptions`. I see that you are assigning the subscription to a variable and probably uing the same to unsubscribe. If your Observable emits multiple time(which I think it doesn't) then during the first emission when it comes to `subscribe()`, the "subscription" variable will be undeifned.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subOb) {
        this.subOb.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

See a sample example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/swicthmap?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

It contains two implementations of switch maps, analyze both and use whatever suites you.

Comment: hi xyz thanks for your help! May I know if its possible to skip the tap and map part and go straight to the second subscribe? e.g. return this.faultService.get(this.deviceid).subscribe(etc.)

Comment: @iBlehhz If you want to execute any logic after the `second` request then you have to use `map` or `tap`. And **No** we are not doing a subscribe on the second API call, switchMap expects an Observable, not a Subscription as a return. We are doing subscription only on the outer API call.

Comment: @iBlehhz: what does the method `first()` do?

Comment: the first method returns the result of the subscription and unsubscribes. I've updated the logic that I used inside the 2nd subscription.. sorry could you show me how I should implement it in your code? I'm still a bit confused.. thanks for your help!!

Comment: @iBlehhz: See the link added in the example

Comment: hey thanks so much!! I figured it out with your help. can't thank you enough you're a life saver :DDD

Comment: @iBlehhz haha, no problem!! :)